# Getting all children from XML imported in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got the following XML that I need to import. I already got the SQL to fill the orders table, but now I want to fill the `order_details` table (with articles).

For the query for the orders is use this:

```
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'orders/mail/order')
```

However I'm not able to get a recordset of all articles (with parent orders) in a second query.

I hoped I could use:

```
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'orders/mail/order/article')
```

but that returns nothing.

```
<orders>
    <mail>
        <set id="s" sequence="1" version="1.1" >
            <property id="calc_vat" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[1]]></property>
            <set id="order" sequence="4" version="">
                <property id="total" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[&#8364; 169,46]]></property>
                <set id="article" sequence="1" version="">
                    <property id="basepricevalue" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[155.66]]></property>
                </set>
                <set id="shipping" sequence="2" version="">
                    <property id="cost-list-used" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[none]]></property>
                    <property id="desc" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[<h5><u><span style&#40;"font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif"><strong>Voor leveringen en datum bel:]]></property>
                </set>
            </set>
        </set>
    </mail>
</orders>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to supply more sample data and what the end result should look like. Based on what you've said, this should help get you started.

```
-- your XML (Note: I added a second "article" for a better sample)
DECLARE @hDoc XML = 
'<orders>
    <mail>
        <set id="s" sequence="1" version="1.1" >
            <property id="calc_vat" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[1]]></property>
            <set id="order" sequence="4" version="">
                <property id="total" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[&#8364; 169,46]]></property>
                <set id="article" sequence="1" version="">
                    <property id="basepricevalue" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[155.66]]></property>
                </set>
                <set id="article" sequence="2" version="">
                    <property id="basepricevalue" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[465.99]]></property>
                </set>
                <set id="shipping" sequence="2" version="">
                    <property id="cost-list-used" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[none]]></property>
                    <property id="desc" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[<h5><u><span style&#40;"font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif"><strong>Voor leveringen en datum bel:]]></property>
                </set>
            </set>
        </set>
    </mail>
</orders>';

-- Possible solution(depending on what you need your final output to look like):
SELECT 
  --nd.x.value('(@id)[1]', 'varchar(8000)'),
  --nd2.x.value('(@id)[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  orderSequence        = nd.x.value('(@sequence)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  orderProperty        = nd.x.value('(property/@id)[1]', 'varchar(8000)'),
  orderPropertyValue   = nd.x.value('(property/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'),
  articleSequence      = nd2.x.value('(@sequence)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  articleProperty      = nd2.x.value('(property/@id)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  articlePropertyValue = nd2.x.value('(property/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM (VALUES (@hDoc)) hdoc(orders)
CROSS APPLY orders.nodes('orders/mail//set[@id="order"]') nd(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('set[@id="article"]') nd2(x);
```

Results:

```
orderSequence orderProperty orderPropertyValue articleSequence articleProperty articlePropertyValue
------------- ------------- ------------------ --------------- --------------- --------------------
4             total         &#8364; 16         1               basepricev      155.66
4             total         &#8364; 16         2               basepricev      465.99
```

Again, if this does not help, please post some more sample data and what you want the final output to look like.

Comment: Hi Alan, this works great thanks!  In my example I only had one property child in article (basepricevalue) while in fact I have about 20.  Is there an easy way to extract them as columns?